# function stopped working after adding more functions

Tags: javascript

I created a function that seems to work until I start adding more functions to the .js document.

This is the html..

```
<input id="nameSearch" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search();"/>
```

This is the js..

```
 function search(){
        var bName = document.getElementById("nameSearch").value;
        alert(bName);
    };
```

This works until I add a new function to the external .js document. I'm not using any of these functions in the html file yet, so I'm not sure why they would affect it.

```
function business(b_name,add_1,add_2,city,state,zip,phone){
    this.b_name = b_name,
    this.add_1 = add_1,
    this.add_2 = add_2,
    this.city = city,
    this.state = state,
    this.zip = zip,
    this.phone = phone,
};

var ADW = new business("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "Tucson", "AZ", "xxx", "xxx-xxx-xxxx");

var PC = new business("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "Tucson", "AZ", "xxx", "xxx-xxx-xxxx");

var contacts = [ADW, PC];
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Look in your developer's console.  Are there are any errors?  (Learning to use your browser's developer console will be *the single best thing* you can do in you want to develop javascript)

Comment: `this.b_name = b_name,` <--- what the comma here is for?

Comment: Yes. It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined" I only get this message after adding the new functions. It works find before that.

Comment: Thanks zerkms. It looks like I should have been using semi-colons to build the constructor rather than commas.

Comment: Thanks cale_b. I am already using Chrome.

Comment: Be aware that Chrome has a pretty aggressive cache, and you'll need to be sure to clear it when developing and making small (or even large) changes to javascript files.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have errors in your `business` function.

I believe you're looking for semi-colons instead of commas:

```
function business(b_name,add_1,add_2,city,state,zip,phone){
    this.b_name = b_name;
    this.add_1 = add_1;
    this.add_2 = add_2;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.phone = phone;
};
```

From a high level, it looks like you're trying to define an object and using the `business` function as an initialization method. You might want to do that instead:

```
let business = {
    b_name: b_name,
    add_1: add_1,
    add_2: add_2,
    city: city,
    state: state,
    zip: zip,
    phone: phone
};
```

[Here's some further reading on the topic.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your console, you will see this error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

It even tells you which line is the problem!

Your issue is that you haven't terminated lines within the function with a semi-colon, you've used commas.

Here's the fix, which runs properly:

```
function business(b_name,add_1,add_2,city,state,zip,phone){
    this.b_name = b_name;
    this.add_1 = add_1;
    this.add_2 = add_2;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.phone = phone;
}

var ADW = new business("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "Tucson", "AZ", "xxx", "xxx-xxx-xxxx");

var PC = new business("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "Tucson", "AZ", "xxx", "xxx-xxx-xxxx");

var contacts = [ADW, PC];
```

And here's [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/s802o3es/) where you can see it runs.